# Matching ICAO codes with latitudes with Python using urllib

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I have been working on a program where ICAO codes are parsed from an online text file as well as their latitudes and longitudes using urllib. The program takes the ICAO codes and plugs them into a url to a different website. So far I've been successful in seeing which urls work and which ones do not, but when I try to print the latitude with the urls that work, they end up giving me a false latitude.

Here is my code...

```
import re
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import time
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import product
from string import *
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib2 import Request,HTTPError, URLError
import time
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import scipy


cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor)
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','mr_anderson')]


keywords = map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3))
keywords = ["k"+a+b+c for a,b,c in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)]

start_time = time.time()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

text_file = open("nws_gov.txt","a")

try:
    a = 1
    b = 1
    c = 0
    List=[""]
for element in range(1,10):
    i=1
    i+=1
    a+=1
    b+=1
    c+=1
    keywargs = str(keywords[a]).upper()
    argument = 'http://weather.rap.ucar.edu/surface/stations.txt'
    sourceCode = opener.open(argument).read()
    airportcode = re.findall(r'\K\w\w\w.*?',str(sourceCode))
    lat  = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}\N',str(sourceCode))
    lata = lat[a]
    arg = 'http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/'+str(airportcode[a])+'.rss'
    try:
        page_open = opener.open(arg)
    except:
        None

    else:
        print(arg+str(lata))

except Exception, e:
    print(str(e))
```

Thanks,

Scott Reinhardt

Comment: Could you please clarify which URL is your ICAO source and which one is the destination URL? Additionally, please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some sample data showing _what_ you mean by _correct_ and _wrong_ output.

Comment: The ICAO source is http://weather.rap.ucar.edu/surface/stations.txt

Comment: So you were able to extract the desired ICAO codes from that file? Please make your code runnable ([MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Where is e.g. `opener`'s definition? And which modules are you importing?

Comment: Here is the whole code

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: Okay I put the whole code in